# Pass json value as ng-model value in angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to bind 2 separate elements so that one can trigger the other. The first step in this, is adding an identifying variable to my component template.
Here's the bullet.html template:

```
<div class="button bullet" ng-model="component.bullet.show_on_click" ng-click="showElementByUniqueName( component.bullet.show_on_click )"><p>{{component.bullet.text}}</p></div>
```

I'd like to know what is the correct syntax to set ng-model as the VALUE in component.bullet.show_on_click. At the moment, in the final html, ng-model turns out just as shown in the template. I have tried single speech marks and single AND double curly braces; All throw errors.

Any help, much appreciated!

**EDIT**

On request, here is some more detail:

The eng-bullet attribute fires up the engBullet directive:

```
app.directive('engBullet', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/bullet.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                // following function referenced in bullet.html
                scope.showElementByUniqueName = function (showOnClick) {

                    // remove 'replaces' element
                    $('#'+$('#'+showOnClick).attr('data-replaces')).addClass('hidden');

                    // hide all popups (in case another popup is currently visible)
                    $('.popup').addClass("hidden");

                    // show selected popup
                    $('#'+showOnClick).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

The eng-popup attribute fires up the engPopup directive:

```
app.directive('engPopup', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'components/popup.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.show = true;
                scope.complete = false;
                // watch for this popup being made visible and check if
                scope.$watch(function() { return element.is(':visible') }, function() {
                    scope.$parent.componentCompleted(attrs.id);
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

..which loads in the components/popup.html template:

```
<div class="hidden popup {{component.popup.type}}" id="{{component.popup.name}}" data-replaces="{{component.popup.replaces}}" eng-completable ng-show="component.popup.name">
    <div ng-if="component.popup.type=='overlay'">
        <div class="float-right button close-button">X</div>
    </div>
    <p class="heading">{{component.popup.heading}}</p>
    <div class="popup-content">
        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(innerIndex, component) in component.popup.popup_components"></div>
            <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="(type, object) in component"></div>
                <div ng-attr-id="{{'p' + pageId + '-s' + skey + '-c' + ckey + '-component-' + index + '-innerComponent-' + innerIndex}}" ng-switch="type">
                    <div ng-switch-when="image" eng-image></div>
                    <div ng-switch-when="paragraph" eng-paragraph></div>
                </div>
            <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
        <div ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure this is really relevant to the question though, which is how do I get the VALUE in component.bullet.show_on_click to present in the final html as the value of ng-model in the bullet html template, eg:

```
ng-model="unique_name_here"
```

?
Thanks.

Comment: You should assign this variable in controller. It will make your trick.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like a little more detail, sorry. I'm getting the component.bullet.show_on_click value from a json file. How would I pass that unique identifier to a controller then? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand a question. Can you give example with two names, and what should do onClick event and I will help you.

Comment: Okay you must be reading a json file and saving it into a variable. If you're having that object in your controller then you can easily pick the value of that json. Json file must contain a valid json, I guess. If you could show your complete json, it'd help us :)

Comment: A `ng-model` on a div element doesn't do anything